# Получить размер загруженного в ImageView изображения

Tags: java, android, imageview, android-imageview

Есть `ImageView`, растянутый на весь экран. В него загружаю картинку, которая располагается по центру(`scaleType:centerInside`).

Необходимо получить ее размеры, которые она получила при масштабировании в `ImageView`. Подскажите как это сделать?

попробовал, ничего не происходит, функция игнорится

```
@Override
public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
    //обработка долгого нажатия, вызов фрагмента
    click_x = (int)e.getRawX();
    click_y = (int)e.getRawY();

    Display display = ((WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();

    int wid = display.getWidth();
    //int wI = mImageViev.getDrawable().getMinimumWidth();
    int www = wid-height;
    int ww =height/2;
    yx =  click_x-ww+28;

    int hei = display.getHeight();
    //int hH = mImageViev.getMeasuredHeight();
    int wwh = hei-width;
    yy= click_y-wwh;

    ViewTreeObserver observer = mImageViev.getViewTreeObserver();
    observer.addOnPreDrawListener(() -> {
        width = mImageViev.getMeasuredWidth();
        height = mImageViev.getMeasuredHeight();

        showToast(height + "x" + width);
        return false;
    });
    //showToast("X: " + yx + " Y: " + yy );
    dialog_add_point dialog = new dialog_add_point();
    dialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "custom");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.myImageView);

ViewTreeObserver observer = imageView.getViewTreeObserver();
observer.addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {
    public boolean onPreDraw() {
        width = imageView.getMeasuredWidth();
        height = imageView.getMeasuredHeight();
        return false;
    }
});
```